# vTaskStartScheduler() overwrites the pointer param values, how to avoid that?

Tags: freertos

I have created a freeRTOS task, and passed a pointer of a struct as the function param.

I noticed the struct property was changed after vTaskStartScheduler()

How do I protect my struct?

Here is the code

Main

```
    xTaskCreate(
                        SHELL_Main, // function the task calls
                        "shell", // nametag for debug console
                        512, // assigned buffersize
                        &user_context,// Parameter passed in
                        1, // task priority
                        NULL); //task handle

    printf("exit=%i", (&user_context)-> exit);
    vTaskStartScheduler();
```

SHELL_Main()

```
int32_t SHELL_Main(p_shell_context_t context)
{

    printf("entered shell_main\n");
    uint8_t ch;
    int32_t i;

    if (!context)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    context->exit = false;
    context->printf_data_func("\r\nSHELL (build: %s)\r\n", __DATE__);
    context->printf_data_func("Copyright (c) 2017 NXP Semiconductor\r\n");
    context->printf_data_func(context->prompt);


    while (1)
    {
      printf("context.exit=%s", (context->exit)?"true\n":"false\n");
      printf("context.exit=%i", (context->exit));

        if (context->exit)
        {
            printf("wtf");
            break;
        }
```

...

Here is the console

```
exit=0entered shell_main

SHELL (build: Oct 26 2018)
Copyright (c) 2017 NXP Semiconductor
SHELL>> context.exit=true
context.exit=253wtf
```

If I call SHELL_Main() directly in main instead of wrapping it in task, here's the console

```
exit=0entered shell_main

SHELL (build: Oct 26 2018)
Copyright (c) 2017 NXP Semiconductor
SHELL>> context.exit=false
context.exit=0
```

I speculate there is an overflow somewhere that overwrites my context.exit after calling vTaskStartScheduler(), but I do not know how to protect my struct. Can someone kindly share some idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SHELL_Main` is what modifies your struct (`context->exit = false;`).  You create that task and pass `context` to it as param.  When you start the scheduler, that task gets run and sets it to `false`.

In fact `vTaskStartScheduler()` never returns.  See doc here: https://www.freertos.org/a00132.html

From comments below, sounds like `printf_data_func()` is causing the issues.  Dig further into it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. that makes sense. I printf the context->exit right after the assignment in SHELL_Main()  and it was not false in the task wrap mode. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: well right after the assignment it is False, and after context->printf_data_func(...) x 3 it become a random number. I will assign a larger stack size. guess it might be insufficient  stack size...

Comment: See my edit.  Also sounds like `printf_data_func` could be causing the trashing.  In fact.  How does that get set and what does the definition look like?

Comment: looks like printf_data_func is the trouble maker. after the first printf_data_func the exit changed from false to true

Comment: Also, what is the definition of `p_shell_context_t`?

Comment: http://mcuxpresso.nxp.com/api_doc/dev/210/group__SHELL.html#structshell__context__struct

Comment: The API doesn't have a field for printf_data_t :-/

Comment: the user_context is shell_context_struct.

Comment: i mean if i take out the & the compile fails :P

Comment: shell source code: https://github.com/aws/amazon-freertos/blob/master/lib/third_party/mcu_vendor/nxp/LPC54018/utilities/fsl_shell.h

Comment: even if i turned off all the printf_data_func, once it entered the while(1) loop, the context.exit become 253

Comment: I think I knew what's the problem. I initialize the user_context in the main() and trie to pass it into the xTaskCreate, the latter might not have right access to the address. Instead I'll create a function that initialize user_context and then call SHELL_main(&user_context) within the same function so that they can access the same memory stack

Answer (score 0):

[This question is old, but I'm adding an answer since it came up in Google search results]

You haven't included the definition of `user_context` in `main()`, but I suspect it's a local. Some ports of FreeRTOS repurpose `main()`'s stack space for use by interrupts, so you can't rely on local variables surviving the call to `vTaskStartScheduler()`. Making `user_context` `static` should solve the problem. See [this FreeRTOS FAQ](https://www.freertos.org/FAQMem.html#RAMReduce).